# How we use fragement on button click in RecylerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

This Is an Full Adapter Code
 It Show an Error NULL Object Please solve Please tell How error remove...........
                package com.softedge.visioneering.tfd.adapters;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.softedge.visioneering.tfd.R;
import com.softedge.visioneering.tfd.fragments.Status_update_Fragment;
import com.softedge.visioneering.tfd.models.OrdersListModel;
import com.softedge.visioneering.tfd.utils.Status_update;

import java.util.List;

import static android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity;

/**
 * Created by Atish Agrawal on 04-12-2016.
 */

public class MyOrdersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyOrdersAdapter.MyOrdersViewHolder> {

    private List<OrdersListModel> list;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


    public MyOrdersAdapter(Context passedContext, List<OrdersListModel> passedModels) {

        this.context = passedContext;
        this.list = passedModels;

    }

    @Override
    public MyOrdersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View convertview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.inner_list_orders, parent, false);


        return new MyOrdersViewHolder(convertview);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyOrdersViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.txtOrderDescription.setText("Title: " + list.get(position).getOrderTitle());
        holder.txtOrderQuantity.setText("Order No.: " + list.get(position).getOrderNumber());
        holder.txtOrderStatus.setText("Status: " + list.get(position).getOrderStatus());
        holder.txtOrderDate.setText("Order Date: " + list.get(position).getOrderCreationDate());
        holder.txtExpectedDate.setText("Exp. Date: " + list.get(position).getExpectedOrderCompletionDate());
        holder.txtCreatedBy.setText("Assign to: " + list.get(position).getAssignToFirstName() + " " + list.get(position).getAssignToLastName());
        holder.txtOrderStatus_Per.setText(list.get(position).getOrderStatusPercentage()+"%");



        if(holder instanceof MyOrdersViewHolder) {

            holder.update_btwn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager =getSupportFragmentManager();
                    //FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.cardViewStudentList, new Status_update_Fragment().newInstance()).addToBackStack("AddEvent").commit();
                    //fragmentTransaction.commit();

                }

                private FragmentManager getSupportFragmentManager() {
                    return null;
                }


            });
        }



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }




    public class MyOrdersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView txtOrderDescription, txtOrderQuantity, txtOrderStatus, txtOrderDate, txtExpectedDate, txtCreatedBy,txtOrderStatus_Per;

        public Button update_btwn;
        public MyOrdersViewHolder(View convertView) {
            super(convertView);

            update_btwn=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status_update_button);
            txtOrderDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtOrderDescription);
            txtOrderQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtOrderQuantity);
            txtOrderStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtOrderStatus);
            txtOrderStatus_Per=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtOrder_Status_per);
            txtOrderDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtOrderDate);
            txtExpectedDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtExpectedDate);
            txtCreatedBy = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCreatedBy);

            /*update_btwn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.cardViewStudentList, new Status_update_Fragment().newInstance()).addToBackStack("AddEvent").commit();
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                }

                private FragmentManager getSupportFragmentManager() {
                    return null;
                }


            });*/




    }


    }
}
```

The code is Adapter code:
        It Shoes Error and I try many Times But it Not solve.
        I am Showing an text using RecylerView. 
    And there I place an Button and want to call fragment on Button Click
    Please Tell me a Solutions

This is My JAVA API class From where I call an adapter Class:

public class OrdersListAPI extends AsyncTask {

```
private static final String TAG = OrdersListAPI.class.getSimpleName();
private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
private String jsonString, response = "";

private OrdersListModel ordersListModel;
private RecyclerView recyclerViewOrders;
private List<OrdersListModel> ordersListModels;
private MyOrdersAdapter myOrdersAdapter;


private Context context;

/**
 * @param callingContext Context of the calling activity
 */

public OrdersListAPI(Context callingContext, RecyclerView passedRecyclerViewOrders,
                     List<OrdersListModel> passedOrderListModels,
                     MyOrdersAdapter passedAdapter, String passedJSON) {
    // Initializing the variables

    this.context = callingContext;
    this.recyclerViewOrders = passedRecyclerViewOrders;
    this.myOrdersAdapter = passedAdapter;
    this.ordersListModels = passedOrderListModels;
    this.jsonString = passedJSON;


}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // Displaying a progressBar
    super.onPreExecute();

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();

}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 *
 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
 */
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // Checking Internet connection

    if (ProjectUtils.isConnectedToInternet(context)) {

        // Connected to internet

        try {

            /**
             * Preparing the URL of the Webserver API
             */

            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ApplicationUtils.RECIEVED_ORDERS_LIST_API);
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


            /**
             *
             * Adding the JSON object to the HTTP-POST
             */

            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonString.toString());
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

            /**
             * Making call to the server
             */

            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);

            /**
             * Checking the response from the server
             */

            int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK || statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {

                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                /**
                 * Fetching response from the server
                 */

                response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                if (ApplicationUtils.isLogEnabled)
                    Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.trim());


                // Processing the response

                JSONArray ordersArray = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < ordersArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject orderJSONObject = ordersArray
                            .getJSONObject(i);

                    /**
                     * Initialising Orders Model
                     */

                    ordersListModel = new OrdersListModel();

                    JSONObject order_det_JSONObject=orderJSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONUtils.EO_ORDER_DETAILS);
                    JSONObject assignToJSONObject = orderJSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONUtils.ASSIGNED_TO);

                    if (TextUtils.equals(assignToJSONObject.getString("primaryKey"),"11")) {
                        /**
                         * Fetching Order Details
                         */

                        ordersListModel.setOrderTitle(order_det_JSONObject.getString(JSONUtils.ORDER_TITLE));
                        ordersListModel.setOrderNumber(order_det_JSONObject.getString(JSONUtils.ORDER_NUMBER));
                        ordersListModel.setOrderStatus(order_det_JSONObject.getString(JSONUtils.ORDER_STATUS));
                        ordersListModel.setOrderCreationDate(order_det_JSONObject.getString(JSONUtils.ORDER_CREATION_DATE));
                        ordersListModel.setExpectedOrderCompletionDate(order_det_JSONObject.getString(JSONUtils.EXPECTED_ORDER_COMPLETION_DATE));
                        ordersListModel.setOrderStatusPercentage(order_det_JSONObject.getString(JSONUtils.ORDER_STATUS_PERCENTAGE));

                        /**
                         * Fetching User Details
                         */
                        //This Show Assign not Created_By
                        //JSONObject createdByJSONObject = orderJSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONUtils.ASSIGNED_TO);

                        ordersListModel.setAssignToFirstName(assignToJSONObject.getString(JSONUtils.FIRST_NAME));
                        ordersListModel.setAssignToLastName(assignToJSONObject.getString(JSONUtils.LAST_NAME));

                        ordersListModels.add(ordersListModel);
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    // Moving to new activity and removing the progress dialog
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
        progressDialog.dismiss();


    // context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Dashboard.class));
    //((Activity) context).finish();

    if (result == null) {

        // User not connected to internet

        Toast.makeText(context, "No Internet connection",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;

    }
    if (result) {

        // Server returned true

        /**
         * Process Response
         */
        myOrdersAdapter = new MyOrdersAdapter(context, ordersListModels);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        recyclerViewOrders.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerViewOrders.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerViewOrders.setAdapter(myOrdersAdapter);

        myOrdersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }


}
```

}

This is an JAVA API from  where it Load Recyler Adapter

Answer (score 1):

Move the `listener` code to `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if(holder instanceof MyOrdersViewHolder) {
           holder.update_btwn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.cardViewStudentList, new Status_update_Fragment().newInstance()).addToBackStack("AddEvent").commit();
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();

                    }

                    private FragmentManager getSupportFragmentManager() {
                        return null;
                    }


                });
        }
    }
```

---

**Edit**, for you other error, my guess that context is an `android.app.Activity`, then do that in the adapter after importing `android.app.Activity`:

```
((Activity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

**OR** simply use the class name of your activity where you call the adapter:

```
 ((YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

instead of this: `getSupportFragmentManager();`

Comment: @RISHABHSAXENA because you need to make the `button` a field variable in your `MyOrdersViewHolder` class!. just like the `textviews`

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null object reference
                      at com.softedge.visioneering.tfd.adapters.MyOrdersAdapter$1.onClick(MyOrdersAdapter.java:74)

Comment: Yes ..Please Solve I am Beginer in Android

Comment: @RISHABHSAXENA Anyway, i guess that it is because you didn't use your context in the adapter. you will have to pass the context (activity reference for example) to the recycler adapter's constructor and then do that, `mContext.getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: Will you please tell me How we do this?

Comment: @RISHABHSAXENA modify your question and add your full adapter code to be able to help you!

Comment: @RISHABHSAXENA I see you have already passed a context to the adapter! just use it. do that `context.getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: I have use but Now It Show  Can not resolove method "getSupportFragmentManager()"

Comment: @RISHABHSAXENA and BTW move the 7 `textviews` statements from `onBindViewHolder` to inside the if block, just above the `button` statement

Comment: @RISHABHSAXENA yeah of course, sorry for that, are you calling it From an activity?

Comment: It is an JAVA File: public class MyOrdersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyOrdersAdapter.MyOrdersViewHolder> {

Comment: @RISHABHSAXENA I meant => Where do you define a new object from the adapter and then use it by `setAdapter()` method? in an activity correct?

Comment: It is call From an API java file

Comment: @RISHABHSAXENA please show me the full code of where you call it!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Solutions is :

    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
```